# Where to validate and test user input date, In the controller or the model?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

Where to clean up/ validate/ verify the user input data? In the controller or the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller.

Look at it this way: Your form will post to a controller function with the form data in $_POST variable. You validate the data in that function of the controller and do some DB inserts or updates. Then you show the success message as a view or in case of error a fail message.

See the form validation tutorial in CodeIgniter's user guide [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the model so your validation can be reused. Models should handle the data and the controller should direct it to where it needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

The code that make the validation must be in the model, but the call to this code must be in the controller.

Something like this:

```
class MyAwesomeUserModel {
   public function isValid()
   {
       //some code to validate the user
   }
}

class MyUserController {
   public function myUserAction()
   {
      //some code to insert the input of the user in the model
      if($userModel->isValid()){
         //do nice things with the data and send some message/data to the view
      } else {
         //send 'nice' error messages to the view
      }
   }
}
```

This is just the way I use, may not be the best way, but it's the best fit in my application. And that's what matters, **you should look for what best suits your application**.